# Assessing column of a datatable by name instead of column index

Tags: powershell

Is there a way, in powershell, to access the information from a column by its column name instead of its column index?

More specifically, I have the following powershell script:

```
$SQLQuery = "select * from fruits"
$server   = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$Database = "Test"
$myTable  = "Fruits"
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$Server';database='$Database';trusted_connection=true;"
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection
$Command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
$Datatable.Load($Reader)
$Connection.Close()

foreach ($r in $Datatable.rows)
{
      Write-Host $($r[1])
}
```

The script prints the data stored in the 2nd column of the table called Fruits ("FruitName") fine, but I wonder if there is a way to assess the 2nd column by referring to FruitName instead?

This is my data structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the column index from the column itself:

```
$FruitNameIndex = $Datatable.Columns['FruitName'].Ordinal
$FruitName = $r[$FruitNameIndex]
```

You could wrap all column indices in a hashtable up front, to avoid long expressions inside the indexer:

```
$ci = $Datatable.Columns |ForEach-Object {$t = @{}} {$t[$_.ColumnName] = $_.Ordinal} {return $t}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$FruitName = $r[$ci.FruitName]
```

Comment: That's awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. That is  very slick.